# External software documentation authoring system and user access permission

Tags: users

We have a scenario where we would like to integrate an external software documentation authoring system that serves the 'Help' about our software with the current website.

The software users based on their user group permission within the cms should only be able to access the documentation meant for them.

For e.g there is one type of permission set for industrial customers, so if an industrial customer while working on the software clicks on 'Help', he/she should then be directed to this external website to the industry specific documentation. One thing to note that our software doesn't distinguish on different customer type.

Comment: You write: "The software users based on their user group permission within the cms should only be able to access the documentation meant for them." and "One thing to note that our software doesn't distinguish on different customer type." This sounds rather contradictory to me. You've designed your software so that it is unable to do what you want it to. The answer is. Then you must re-design your software to do what you want. We can't design your software for you.

Comment: @FreeRadical I appreciate the fact that you took time to read my question but I wasn't nowhere seeking suggestion to re-design the software.

Comment: I'm sorry, but then I do not understand what you're asking. There is no question in your question. (But perhaps somebody smarter than me is able to figure it out.)

Comment: @FreeRadical I can try explain again but it could also be true that someone might be able to slightly figure out what I am trying to ask for.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Thanks for your response and sorry for such an unclear query. I would get back on this with better phrased words.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Yes, I meant 'I will' so here is my question again (i hope it makes some sense now :) ) - Is it possible to display data from an external website (html) on a drupal website? Our software documentation is hierarchical structure of html pages on an external website, so we were trying to find out if it is possible to make this available to users through our drupal website .